# Synchronizing theme changes with Creative Exchange Live

Tags: sxa, creative-exchange, sxa-cli

I set up my project with Creative Exchange Live using SXA CLI, everything works when I use "sxa watch" my files are well compiled and send to the server.

The issue is when I try to get the changes made by an other developer on the theme, I use the [recommended command](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/sxa/101/sitecore-experience-accelerator/automating-tasks-using-sxa-cli.html#updating-assets_body) "sxa rebuild All" but it only seems to upload my files and I don't get the new files and the changes created by the other developer.
Do you know how I can get this to work ?

Thanks !

Comment: What have you tried and what errors if any are you getting? If you have pulled all the latest changes from your repo and use `sxa rebuild All` that should take everything, build and upload the theme into Sitecore. Are you using a local Sitecore instance or are you sharing a Sitecore instance with other FEDs?

Comment: I don't have any error, I just have those messages:
 Js minification done
Sass build done
Css minification done

In fact I don't use a repo for now, maybe it is the problem.
I share a sitecore instance with others, I don't have a local sitecore instance

Comment: If you share the instance, then that is your problem. if others are using a watch, any time they make a change, it will upload the entire theme, and they won't have your changes, so they will get overwritten. Developers should all work on their own local copy of Sitecore, never use a shared instance for developing themes, it doesn't work.

Comment: Also use the `--debug` flag to get more information about what is going on